# Erro de conexão

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando uma aplicação Windows Forms usando C# e estou tendo um problema com a conexão com o SQL Server CE 4.0.

O banco de dados do aplicativo está na pasta `AppData` do usuário logado. Para pegar o caminho da pasta `AppData` eu utilizo o `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` que no meu caso retorna *"C:/Users/richard.dias/AppData/Roaming/"*.

Dentro desta pasta eu tenho a seguinte estrutura: Nome da empresa/Nome do aplicativo. Isso resulta no caminho `C:/Users/richard.dias/AppData/Roaming/Nome da empresa/Nome do aplicativo/`.

Na pasta do aplicativo o banco de dados fica dentro da pasta `App_Data`.

Para fazer a conexão estou passando o caminho absoluto para o arquivo `.SDF` do banco de dados e a senha para a conexão.

Resultado final da string de conexão: `Data Source=C:/Users/richard.dias/AppData/Roaming/Nome da empresa/Nome do aplicativo/App_Data/bd.sdf;Password=123456;`

Código para a abertura de conexão:

```
using (var conexao = new SqlConnection(STR_CON))
using (var comando = new SqlCommand())
{
    comando.CommandText = sql;
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", p1);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", p2);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", p3);

    conexao.Open();

    comando.Connection = conexao;
    obteveSucesso = comando.ExecuteNonQuery() == 3;

    conexao.Close();
}
```

Ao entrar abrir a conexão ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL Server)

ou em inglês:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Alguém usa a mesma senha que eu, tenho que trocar a senha da maleta... :D

Comment: Brincadeiras a parte, você consegue abrir a base de dados com algum programa como o próprio Visual Studio, ou algum da suíte do SQL Management? Se sim, verifique se não há alguma diferença na forma como esses programas montam a string de conexão. No Visual Studio você pode ver a string (com a senha mascarada) na aba de propriedades, ao selecionar a conexão.

Comment: Não sabia disso @Renan. Olhei como vc falou no VS e a única diferença que percebi é que o o valor da propriedade `Data Source` fica entre aspas duplas. tentei remover os espaços dos nomes das pastas no caminho e também não funcionou.

Comment: Assim fica difícil. Recomendo duas coisas: assegurar-se de que está a usar o driver correto no seu programa, e verificar se consegue abrir a base com o Visual Studio.

Comment: Já verifiquei o driver, e também já abri a base com o VS. Não sei mais o que fazer para tentar resolver este problema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você deve utilizar `SqlCeConnection`, `SqlCeCommand` e similares ao invés de `SqlConnection`. Adicione uma referência a `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`.

<sub>**[Original]**</sub>

You must use `SqlCeConnection`, `SqlCeCommand` etc instead of `SqlConnection`. Add a reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Sua resposta está certa! Eu mudei meu código e tudo funcionou bem.

Comment: Hi, Erik, welcome to the portuguese side of the Stack. I'd suggest that you do a Google translate when answering or maybe add a footnote: *"please, feel free to translate this answer"*. Of course, we are already free to do that, but it's a nice detail.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember to do that!

Comment: Obrigado, vou lembrar de fazer isso! :-)